# mongoexport using --query in command line prompt in windows

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, command-line-interface, mongoexport

**mongoexport --uri="mongoDB srv string" -c products0 -o C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\json\test.json --limit 1000 --query='{crawler : "flipkart"}'**

When i try using this mongo export command, it gives error while running this command **parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: provide only one MongoDB connection string. Connection strings must begin with mongodb:// or mongodb+srv:// schemes**

Tried with quotes spaces or equal sign operator.

When i tried without --query it works perfectly fine.

I am using mongodb version 4.4.1.

Can any body tell me, what is missing in this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows command prompt does not support single quotation marks.

Try using

```
"{\"crawler\": \"flipkart\"}"
```