# MongoDb 3.2 export collection by entries greater than a date

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to export a collection from MongoDB with all entries greater than a specific date. I am using the 3.2 documentation found here https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongoexport/.

This is what i tried to do

C:\mongodb\bin>mongoexport -d=mydb -c=mydata -q='{  time: {$gte: { "$date": "2021-02-02T00:00:00.000Z" } } }' --out=myRecords.json

Outcome

2021-09-15T11:08:39.936-0700    too many positional arguments: [time: {$gte: { $date: 2021-02-02T00:00:00.000Z } } }']
2021-09-15T11:08:39.936-0700    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information

If i leave the query out, it works

Comment: Using `'` around a command line argument doesn't work in windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongoexport using --query in command line prompt in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68928075/mongoexport-using-query-in-command-line-prompt-in-windows)

Comment: i downloaded git bash and the above worked. Have not tried the suggestions